# All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: PC

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am doing Spring Dao with cassandra DB.But i unable to made the connection.

**I am getting this Error**

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All
>   host(s) tried for query failed (tried: PC264506/10.249.67.4:9042
>   (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException:
>   [PC264506/10.249.67.4:9042] Cannot connect))  at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:223)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:78)
>     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1230)
>     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:157)  at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:245)    at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:278)    at
>   org.spring.cassandra.example.CassandraApp.main(CassandraApp.java:32)

My POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.spring.cassandra.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>app-cass-tutorial1</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>app-cass-tutorial1</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>spring-milestone</id>
    <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  </project>
```

And i verified cassandra.yaml settings also...

Comment: have you checked this link?:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795479/all-hosts-tried-for-query-failed-error

Comment: check this too may it will help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783725/error-while-connecting-to-cassandra-using-java-driver-for-apache-cassandra-1-0-f

Comment: Solved it following @Soora 's link :)